# Would I be correct to assume that the minimum amount of vertices required to have an object with 3 dimensions is 4?

Tags: geometry

The question seems so simple to me but often the simplest ones are the most complex. My assumption is that the minimum amount of points required to create an object with 3 dimensions is 4?

You would get a tetrahedron as far as I am aware. What I mean exactly is the minimum amount of points / vertices to create an object which has an exterior and interior, or another way of putting it would be that it has a volume. I am not well versed enough in geometry to use the proper terminology but I hope this is clear. Is this correct, that the minimum amount of points for such an object is 4?

Comment: It is true that given any three (or fewer) points, they are always coplanar and so, you get a 2D (or lower) object. However, four points need not always give a tetrahedron. For example, the four points could be colinear. (So you don't even get a 2D object.)

Comment: A 3D sphere has no vertices but it is an object in three dimensions.. I think you should be more clear in "what kind of objects are you talking about".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean a three-dimensional solid by 'object', then yes, that is correct. Three (non-collinear) points are needed to define a plane in 3D space, so the minimum number of points to do so cannot be 3 or less. Since a tetrahedron has 4 vertices, the minimum number of points for a $3$D object to exist is therefore 4.

The fact that "three points define a plane" comes from the fact that any plane can be written as $ax + by + cz = d$. The rank of the augmented matrix with $n$ rows is at most $n$, so at least $3$ equations are needed for the matrix to have rank $3$ (which is a full rank in $3$D space). For a less technical explanation, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743058/why-do-three-non-collinears-points-define-a-plane).

Answer (score 2):

Formalizing your statement, what you are saying is that the convex hull of $3$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is contained in some affine plane.

That is true: Given $\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, any vector in their convex hull lies in the affine subspace $\vec{x}+\langle \vec{y}-\vec{x}, \vec{z}-\vec{x}\rangle$, which is at most two dimensional:
$$
\lambda \vec{x}+\mu \vec{y} +\nu \vec{z}= \vec{x}+ \mu(\vec{y}-\vec{x})+\nu(\vec{z}-\vec{x})
$$
whenever $\lambda,\mu,\nu\in[0,1]$ satisfy $\lambda+\mu+\nu=1$.