# Prove some results in a cube...

Tags: solution-verification, solid-geometry, rectangles

**Question**

Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a cube and the points $M, N, Q$ the means of the sides $A'B', A'D', DC$. We denote by $\alpha=(MNQ)$.

a) If the line $D'C'$ intersects the plane $\alpha$ at the point $T$, prove that $A'T\equiv MD'$

b) Let $P$ be the intersection of the plane $\alpha$ with $DD'$ and let $S$ be the intersection of the plane $\alpha$ with $BB'$. Prove that the quadrilateral $PQSM$ is a rectangle

**Idea**

*drawing*

[image]

The first thought that came into my mind was showing that $A'MD'T$ is a parallelogram.

Because $T\in D'C' => TD'|| A'M$

We also know that $N$ is mid point of $A'D'$

Using the midline theorem we can express $NM=\frac{l\sqrt{2}}{2}$, where $l$ is the side of the cube.

If we can show that $TN$ is also equal to $NM$ the first point will be done, but I don't know where to start and what to do(I'm kinda new to the geometry in space).

*answer using @Calvin Lin's idea*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope one of you can help! Thank you!

Comment: Please use proper tags, thank you.

Comment: How is this question about modular arithmetic?

Comment: @BenjaminWang sorry, i pressed wrong the button

Comment: @jjagmath sorry, i pressed the wrong button

Comment: 1/ Your cube should be $ABCD A'B'C'D'$? 2 / What is $T'$ in $A'T' \equiv M D'$?  3/ Please edit away the modular-arithmetic tag. 4/ Given that in a previous question you stated that you don't know coordinate geometry, are we allowed to use vectors?

Comment: @CalvinLin I edited the typos. If you can, I will apreciate not using the vectors. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your proof is fine.

In the following, I'm going to write some comments and another proof.

Some comments : In your proof that $M,N,T$ are collinear, it might be better to explicitly say that you used the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3743075/78967) that given three non collinear points, only one plane goes through them. Also, it might be better to add a few explanations about why $PQSM$ is a rectangle when $PQ=MS,PQ\parallel MS$ and $PS=MQ$.

Another proof that $M,N,T$ are collinear : Using the fact that the intersection of two non-parallel planes in three-dimensional space is a line, we can say that the intersection of $\alpha$ and the plane $A'B'C'D'$ is the line $MN$. It follows that $M,N,T$ are collinear. (Also, it follows that $M,N,T'$ are collinear.)

Answer (score 0):

Steps towards a solution. Fill in the details as needed.
If you're stuck, explain what you've tried, and why it doesn't work.
Geometry in 2-D is often easier than geometry in 3-D, so try to force things to happen on a plane as much as possible.

a) You're on the right track.
Show that $ T = MN \cap D'C'$.  -> This demystifies the intersection of the plane and some line.
Hence $TND' \cong MNA'$ by ASA.
Hence $A'T = MD'$.

b) Let $R$ be the midpoint of $BC$.
Show that $MNQR$ is in the same plane, and form a rectangle.
Show that $P$ is the midpoint of $DD'$, and $S$ is the midpoint of $BB'$.  -> This is arguably the crux.
Show that $MNPQRS$ is a regular hexagon.
Hence $PQSM$ is also a rectangle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I uploaded some photos on my answer using your idea. Still, can you take a look and tell me if I solved it right? I uploaded photos because the solution is so long. Let me know if you don't understand what i wrote.