# Prove that the planes $( M_k N_k P_k )$ have the same direction for any positive strictly real number $k$

Tags: geometry

**Question**

We consider the cube $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ and the points: $M_k \in ( A' D'), N_k \in ( C C' ), P_k \in ( A B )$ so that:

> $\frac{A' M_k}{M_k D'}= \frac{C' N_k}{N_k C}= \frac{B P_k}{P_k A}=k$

where $k$ is a strictly positive real number.

Prove that the planes $( M_k N_k P_k )$ have the same direction for any positive strictly real number $k$

*drawing*

[image]

*My idea*

I let the point $M_a, M_b, N_a, N_b, P_a, P_b$ where $a,b$ are some values that $k$ can take, just so I can un-generalise the problem.

If we can show that $(M_AN_AP_A)$ is parallel with $(M_BN_BP_B)$, then I believe the problem should be solved.

If yes, I don't know where to start. I think using the reciprocal of Thales' theorem will help but I don't know where to start.

I say this cause I don't understand how I should prove that some planes have the same direction.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: The OP keeps editing the title just to add "HELP ME UNDERSTAND ANSWER".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may suppose that the length of a side of the cube is $1$.

Then, we have
$$M_kD'=P_kA=N_kC=\frac{1}{k+1}$$
$$M_kA'=P_kB=N_kC'=\frac{k}{k+1}$$

Let $E$ be a point on $C'D'$ such that $ED'=\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $EC'=\frac{k}{k+1}$.

Let $F$ be a point on $BC$ such that $CF=\frac{1}{k+1}$ and $FB=\frac{k}{k+1}$.

Let $G$ be a point on $AA'$ such that $GA'=\frac{k}{k+1}$ and $GA=\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Let $H$ be the intersection point of $EM_k$ with $B'A'$.

Let $I$ be the intersection point of $EM_k$ with $B'C'$.

Let $J$ be the intersection point of $N_kF$ with $B'B$.

Then, the points $E,F,G,H,I,J$ are on the plane $M_kN_kP_k$. (I think you see why.)

Since
$$A'H=C'I=BJ=\frac{k}{k+1}$$
we have
$$B'B:B'J=B'A':B'H=B'C':B'I$$
So, we can say that the plane $HIJ$, i.e. the plane $M_kN_kP_k$ is parallel to the plane $BA'C'$.

Therefore, the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea! I don't really understand why the points $E,F,G,H,I,J$ are on the plane $M_kN_kP_k$...I see that $M_k E|| P_KF$, which makes $M_kEFP_k$ a parallelogram so $M_kP_k||EF$ From here we have 2 possibilities: 1) EF is parallel with that plane or 2) EF $\in$ that plane .what should I do next?

Comment: @IONELA BUCIU : Let me explain my idea. It is sufficient to prove that $F,G,H,I,J,N_k$ are on the plane $M_kEP_k$. Using the idea written in [this your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800414/prove-some-results-in-a-cube), we can say that $H,I$ are on the plane. Then, we can say that $G,J$ are on the plane. Then, we can say that $F,N_k$ are on the plane. Does this help?

Comment: Sorry, but i can't figure out if we can say that $G,J, F, N_k$
 are on the plane, but I succeeded in showing that HI are on that plane... I think the intersection might be wrong. Thank you!

Comment: there is $M_k,E,I,H$ that are in the planes $(A'B'C'D')$ and $(M_KEP)$ which means they are collinear

Comment: @IONELA BUCIU : The line $M_kE$ is the intersection of the plane $A'B'C'D'$ with the plane $M_kEP_k$. Since $H,I$ are on the line $M_kE$, the two points $H,I$ are on the plane $M_kEP_k$. The line $HP_k$ is the intersection of the plane $A'B'BA$ with the plane $M_kEP_k$. Since $G,J$ are on the line $HP_k$, the two points $G,J$ are on the plane $M_kEP_k$. The line $JI$ is the intersection point of the plane $BCC'B'$ with the plane $M_kEP_k$. Since $N_k,F$ are on the line $JI$, the two points $N_k,F$ are on the plane $M_kEP_k$.

Comment: i understand the idea, but how you know that $G,J$ are on the $HP_k$ line... ,, Using the idea written in this your question" I don't think would help/

Comment: @IONELA BUCIU : Three triangles $\triangle{HA'G},\triangle{GAP_k}$ and $\triangle{P_kBJ}$ are isosceles right triangles with $HA'=A'G,GA=AP_k$ and $P_kB=BJ$. Since $\angle{A'HG}=\angle{A'GH}=\angle{AGP_k}=\angle{AP_kG}=\angle{BP_kJ}=\angle{BJP_k}$, we see that $G,J$ are on the line $HP_k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be the rotation around the axis $B'D$ by $120^\circ$. Note that: $r(B)=C'$, $r(C')=A'$ and $r(A')=B$. Also $r(A)=C$, $r(C)=D'$, $r(D')=A$. Since $P_k, N_k, M_k$ divide the segments $BA$, $C'C$, $A'D'$, respectiely, with equal ratio, it follows that $r(P_k)=N_k$, $r(N_k)=M_k$, $r(M_k)=P_k$. In particular, $P_kN_kM_k$ is an equlateral triangle contained in a plane perpendicular to the axis of rotation $r$. This shows that regardless of what $k$ is, the direction of the plane $P_kN_kM_k$ is the same.

Answer (score -6):

** Produced by ChatGPT

The problem you're working on involves proving that certain planes within a cube are parallel for any positive real number $ k $. This is a geometry problem that can be approached using vector geometry or analytical geometry methods.

Given the cube $ ABCDA'B'C'D' $ and the points $ M_k $ on $ (A'D') $, $ N_k $ on $ (C'C) $, and $ P_k $ on $ (AB) $, where the distances $ \overline{A'M_k} $, $ \overline{C'N_k} $, and $ \overline{BP_k} $ are in the ratio of $ k $ to the lengths $ \overline{M_kD'} $, $ \overline{N_kC} $, and $ \overline{P_kA} $ respectively, you want to show that the planes $ (M_kN_kP_k) $ are all parallel to each other for any value of $ k $.

Here's a sketch of how you might proceed with a proof:

1. Define the cube with vertices at coordinate points for ease of calculation. For example, let $ A $ be at the origin (0,0,0), and since it's a cube, let each edge be of unit length.
2. Express the coordinates of $ M_k $, $ N_k $, and $ P_k $ in terms of $ k $. For example:

   - $ M_k $ would be $ (0, k/(k+1), 1) $.
   - $ N_k $ would be $ (1, 1, k/(k+1)) $.
   - $ P_k $ would be $ (k/(k+1), 0, 0) $.
3. Determine the vectors that lie on the plane $ (M_kN_kP_k) $. Two such vectors can be determined by taking $ \vec{M_kN_k} $ and $ \vec{M_kP_k} $.
4. Find the normal vector to the plane $ (M_kN_kP_k) $ using the cross product of the vectors found in step 3. The normal vector will give you the direction perpendicular to the plane.
5. Show that the normal vector is independent of $ k $, which would imply that the direction perpendicular to each of these planes is the same for all $ k $, and hence the planes are parallel.
6. Alternatively, if the direction vectors of the planes (found in step 3) are proportional for different values of $ k $, this would also imply that the planes are parallel.

Remember, two planes are parallel if and only if their normal vectors are proportional, or equivalently, if direction vectors lying on the planes are proportional. If you demonstrate that the vectors you find in step 3 or the normal vectors from step 4 do not change direction as $ k $ varies (they may change in length, but not in direction), then you have proven that the planes are parallel for any $ k $.

This approach relies on being precise with vector calculations and careful in the manipulation of expressions involving $ k $. The algebra can become complex, so meticulousness is key. If you'd like, I can walk you through the detailed calculations of these steps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your idea. But is there any way to transform this answer into one that doesn't use vector geometry or analytical geometry methods? Im didn't learn about them yet at school.

Comment: -1 for "Produced by ChatGPT"